# Two Dimensional Char Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, char

Recently when I am doing code in C, I need declare a two dimensional array as follows:

```
char foo[20][20];
```

Later I will assign character arrays in to the `foo`.

After that I need to copy these strings into some other variables.

Copying goes like this:

```
strcpy(date, foo[0]);
strcpy(name, foo[1]);
strcpy(des, foo[6]);
strcpy(cpy, foo[2]);
```

Since I did not maintained the sequence while copying like `foo[0]`, `foo[1]`, `foo[6]` and `foo[2]`, I got some garbage to `p3` along with the original string.
Later I corrected the sequence to `foo[0]`, `foo[1]`, `foo[2]` and `foo[6]` in copying and I got the expected result.

Please give clarity on this.

Actually the pointers p1, p2, p3 and p4 are the variables in a structure.
Structure goes likes:

```
struct sample
{
    char date[9];
    char name[8];
    char des[8];
    char cpy[9];
};
```

Comment: Do those `p` strings have space allocated for them?  What you have in your example isn't legal syntax, so it's clear it's not your real code.

Comment: Would be better if you could post the full code.

Comment: Post your actual code, and show how foo is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Option one is that you did not initialize you structure or your array to 0, first check that you call memset() correctly on both, use sizeof() to make sure.

Option two is that you overrun the struct member sizes, you may want to use strncpy() instead, again, with sizeof().

Comment: I used memset and I replaced strcpy with strncpy, even then the problem persists